# Подключение yandex map в react проекте

Tags: javascript, reactjs, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Не совсем понимаю как подключать API yandex map к react, в документации https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/3.0/quick-start/index.html#load-api указано что через html это надо делать, но как же подключить в самом react, пробовал через index.html, не вышло

Comment: Есть же информация по этому поводу:

https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/dg/concepts/general#react

Answer (score 1):

Для интеграции API Yandex Maps в проект на React удобно воспользоваться сторонней библиотекой, которая упростит процесс. Одним из таких инструментов является [React Yandex Maps](https://pbe-react-yandex-maps.vercel.app/). Вот пример того, как можно использовать эту библиотеку:

Установи библиотеку с помощью npm:

```
npm install react-yandex-maps
```

Импортируй компоненты из библиотеки в файле React-компонента:

```
import { YMaps, Map, Placemark } from 'react-yandex-maps';
```

Используй компоненты в JSX:

```
 function MyMap() {
  return (
    <YMaps>
      <Map defaultState={{ center: [55.751574, 37.573856], zoom: 9 }}>
        <Placemark geometry={[55.751574, 37.573856]} />
      </Map>
    </YMaps>
  );
}

export default MyMap;
```

Замени значения `center` и `geometry` на координаты выбранного местоположения.

Comment: Кажется, это для второй версии, а не для третьей?

Answer (score 1):

Для 3-й версии есть модуль `reactify`, из него можно получить компоненты примерно так:

```
import React, {useEffect, useMemo} from "react";
import {features, LOCATION} from './helpers'

function Map() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(); 
  const {
    YMap,
    // ...other components
  } = useMemo(() => {
    if (data?.reactify) {
      return reactify.module(data.ymap);
    }
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = `https://api-maps.yandex.ru/v3/?apikey=${key}&lang=${lang}`;
    script.onload = async () => {
      const ymaps = window.ymaps3
      await ymaps.ready;
      const ymaps3Reactify = await ymaps.import('@yandex/ymaps3-reactify');
      const reactify = ymaps3Reactify.reactify.bindTo(React, ReactDOM);

      setData({
        reactify,
        ymaps
      });
      /*
      and other logic which is not connected with rendering
      to load ymap modules like YMapDefaultMarker
      */
    }
  }, [])
  
  if (!YMap) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <YMap location={location}>
      <YMapDefaultSchemeLayer/>
      <YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer/>
      <YMapDefaultMarker
        coordinates={LOCATION.coordinates}
      />
    </YMap>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

Однако, можно и из [библиотеки ymap3-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ymap3-components) достать компоненты через `import`:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  YMap,
  YMapDefaultSchemeLayer,
  YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer
  // ...other components
} from "ymapv3-components";
import { features, LOCATION } from './helpers'

function Map() {
  return (
    <YMapComponentsProvider apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_YMAP_KEY}>
      <YMap location={location}>
        <YMapDefaultSchemeLayer />
        <YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer />
        <YMapDefaultMarker
          coordinates={LOCATION.coordinates}
        />
      </YMap>
    </YMapComponentsProvider>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

Также учитывайте, что для работы с 3-м api нужно выполнить следующие шаги:

1. Получить ключ для [map js api](https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/services/3)
2. Установить домен, где будет работать сайт с картой
3. Для разработки удобно поменять `/etc/hosts`, потому что карта будет запускаться только на сайте, где `referer` такой же, как установленный домен